# Typescript type definition

Tags: angular, typescript

In Typescript 2.2, I'd like to define a property in a class which is an object containing some other object of type Subscription.
If it was an array of Subscription, i would have write it like :
`subs: Subscription[];`

How to define it with an object and not an array ? Thank you.

Comment: Just take off the braces.

Comment: If i write that :
subs: Subscription = {};
There's an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
subs: {sub?: Subscription};
```

Usage:

```
this.subs = {sub: subscription};
```

or if you want multiple subscriptions in there:

```
subs: {[id: string]: Subscription};
```

Usage:

```
this.subs = {sub1: subscription1, sub2: subscription2};
```

Comment: And if I want to init subs with an empty object ? ( this.subs = {} )

Comment: subs: {sub: Subscription} = {} doesn't work, but subs: {[id: string]: Subscription} = {} is fine, thank you !

Comment: I've updated my answer for the first solution with just one `Subscription`. The `?` makes the property optional, which means the object can either be empty or contain just one property with the name `sub`